# how to handle UpdatePanel before async result comes

Tags: asp.net

Ok, i renew my question.
Can I use UpdatePanel to handle this way.
You know, everything in the ContentTemplate, will be async, but how we handle the result before the result comes.
like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="info" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

when we click the button, it will query the database in back-end, which need some time, maybe several seconds, maybe longer. now how can i make the info label to display "querying", indicate the processing in back-end, the visitor should be wait for some while.

Comment: This question does not make sense. There is one Content Template. It does not know "sending" or "processing" (it just "runs") or "success". It is just a template that runs within the "normal page-lifecycle" (and is instantiated by the UpdatePanel). Now, the *client side* Page Request Manager, does track those events: it can tell when a (partial postback) request started (was sent to the server) and when it returned from the server (and what the result was).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ProgressTemplateuse ProgressTemplateuse ProgressTemplateuse ProgressTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Add update proggress to your update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="myUpdatePanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="info" runat="server" Text="querying..."/>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

See more options and samples on **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**.

Comment: I do this, it is ok, but soemtimes, it did not show the Progress Template, i try to debug, but did not know how to do

Comment: It is hard to debug Microsoft's ajax controls. That is why jQuery is so popular now. Try to capture traffic (fiddler, network tab in dev tools or firebug) to see if http request is really pending when you get no progress.